# Facebook - How to Pragmatically post to facebook page? | Refreshing Access Token

Tags: java, spring, facebook, facebook-access-token

So I have been stuck on this for a while, I'm trying to post from my web application (Spring boot) **AUTOMATICALLY** without any user interaction, NO POPUP LOGIN VIA FB OR AUTHORIZE FB ACTION nothing.

My application itself should do this. I achieved this by using :

```
    public String postStatusOnPage(String message) {
    if (socialFacebookConfiguration.isEnableWorkaroundAutoPost()) {
        String id = facebook.pageOperations().post(new PagePostData(socialFacebookConfiguration.getPageId()).message(message));
        log.log(Level.INFO, "Created New post id: " + id);
        return id;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This works all ok. Bud , there is an issue and i dont know if my solution is really a right way to do it.

Im getting **facebook The authentication has expired.**

My access token that i have defined in application.properties

```
workaround.social.facebook.accessToken=...
```

Will expire. I dont know about how to refresh it. I have cheated a bit by using 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

[image]

> Question :

**So How do I automatically get new access token? Is this a correct way of doing this OR is there better way? Is there a possibility to have access token that never expires?**

Side note : MY application has OAuth2 login via google, bud I want application itself to do this, without any user being logged in(administrator as a human).

There is another token that i have , its app token

[image]

Bud this one does not work for posting to my page. On invocation throws :

> faceboook An active access token must be used to query information
>   about the current user.

Answer (score 1):

An App Token does not have any relation to a User or Page. You MUST use a Page Token to post to your Page, and you can use an **Extended Page Token** for that.

More information about Tokens: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Comment: Yhe, i hate the fact that i will still have to get UAC to get EPT.